# $\mathbb{E}(Y^r)=k<1$ implies $Y$ is a Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability-theory

> Prove that if, for all positive integers $r$, $\mathbb{E}(Y^r)=k<1$,
>   then $Y$ follows a Bernoulli distribution.

The statement is intuitively trivial, in my opinion. But I can't come up with a rigorous proof.

**Attempt 1:**

We know that moment generating function (m.g.f) completely determines the distribution, we try to compare the m.g.f.'s:

M.g.f. of Bernoulli distribution, with parameter $p = 1-p+pe^t$

M.g.f. of $Y = \sum e^{ty} f(y)$

To get something similar to the assumption, I tried to expand $e^{ty}$ in taylor series. But it doesn't seem useful.

**Attempt 2:** (more like a wild guess...)

$\mathbb{E}(Y^1)+\mathbb{E}(Y^2)+\mathbb{E}(Y^3) + \cdots = (1+1+\cdots)p(1)+(2+4+8+\cdots)p(2) + (3+9+27+\cdots)p(3) + \cdots$

But the LHS equals infinity...

*It is a homework question.* Please give me some hints instead of posting the answers directly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that
$$M_Y(t)=E(e^{tY})=1+E(Y)t+\frac{E(Y^2)}{2!}t^2+\frac{E(Y^3)}{3!}t^3+\cdots.$$

Comment: Thanks! Now that everything is clear!

Comment: You are welcome. I take it you found the further manipulation to put the series in the right form.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
If $P$ is probability of $Y$, than following equalities hold
$$k=\int y dP(y) = \int y^2 dP(y) = \int y^3 dP(y) = \ldots = \int y^n dP(y) = \ldots  $$
if follows that 
$$0= \int y - y^2 dP(y)$$
so basically $P(Y = Y^n)=1 ~ \forall n$. What can you conclude from it about possible values of $Y$?